# Can't open a dynamic link from facebook to my app

Tags: flutter, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

I've generated a dynamic link from my app to be shared to social apps like Facebook, Twitter and whatsapp. It works on Twitter and Whatsapp properly but in case of Facebook, it doesn't redirect my to the deep link created to my app.

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

// dl: a dynamic link created using firebase dynamic links

// Doesn't work as expected
launchUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=$dl"), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)

// Works as expected
launchUrl(Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=$dl"), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)

// Works as expected
launchUrl(Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=$dl"), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)
```